# "За полночь" — ударение в контексте

Tags: орфоэпия

*"Зулейха открывает глаза":*

> Так было положено начало семрукскому колхозу и успешно закрыт второй пункт повестки дня, к тому времени уже перевалившего ***за полночь***.

Как правильно поставить ударение: на само слово или на предлог?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы поставил на предлог. 
Вообще подобные образования обычно допускают двоякое ударение, но в художественном тексте, да еще с учетом относительной современности действия, ударение просится именно туда.

Тут есть возражение, что такое ударение более свойственно наречию, в то время как в тексте оборот явно не в наречном значении. Но, думаю, это не так существенно, чтобы говорить об энклитическом построении (безударном предлоге).

Comment: Спасибо большое! Современность в смысле что указывается на непосредственное время действия? Нашёл слово "энклитический" — у вас опечатка?

Comment: Ну да, опечатка, спасибо. Современность - в том смысле, что в отношении описания событий века этак девятнадцатого я бы не был столь уверен.

Answer (score 2):

В разных источниках указывается, что ударение падает именно на предлог.

http://slovonline.ru/slovar_udarenie/b-8/id-35723/za_polnoch.html
[http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?all=x&word=полночь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?all=x&word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%8C) || Здесь же словарь "Русское словесное ударение".
И даже отдельным пунктом в толковом словаре Ефремовой:
https://www.efremova.info/word/za_polnoch.html

Comment: Вообще да, я просто сомневался, в любом ли контексте, например, как у меня, в ненаречном значении (как Бегемотус верно подметил).

Comment: А есть и пример, когда другое ударение. Этому способствует слово "далеко". https://где-ударение.рф/в-слове-полночь/

Comment: Ну не знаю, непонятно, кто это так решил и почему.